# Usage of "Have to" before The Middle Ages

Tags: syntax, language-evolution, word-choice, word-usage

Medieval-esque phrases like "habeo abire" and "is habet scire" do not *break the rules* of Classical Latin, but I know that they were much more common afterward. This construction interests me greatly, because it's yet another "weird English thing" explained. However, as you might expect, it's quite difficult to search through an online corpus (if only *corpus* had a different accusative so that I could do a "or shall I say" thing) when the word *habere* has so many meanings. So my question is: how was "have to" used before the Middle Ages? Was it recorded at all? When was it first encountered? What were the opinions on it's usage at the time? I wouldn't consider these as multiple questions, but rather as suggestions for the ways in which one could answer my question.

Comment: Just to clarify, I need information about "habere" specifically, not synonyms like "debere."

Comment: As a start, take a look at Lewis and Short at the end of I.A  for habeo: "with inf. or with the part. fut. pass. (ante-class. and post-Aug.), to have or be obliged to do something, I must do something."  There are some examples that should be of interest to you.  :http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dhabeo

Comment: You could always do a "or shall I say *corpum*?" and we could do a "no!". // I added some tags. Do you think the new tag [tag:time-periods] is included in the existing [tag:language-evolution]? I'm not sure if both are needed.

Comment: I know of a construction that was probably more common than the use of _habere_: _necesse est_, so that may or may not be relevant.

Comment: Necesse est is the most common thing to say, but I'm interested in its formality and the scenes in which one would use habere. Necesse est quod donatis mihi cogitationes scriptorum mediaevalium et rogationem meam respondetis. Sciebam bene de "necesse," sed gratias tibi ago certe. (Finaliter scribebam aliquid quod rectum est sine glossario!)

Comment: The word *corpus* always reminds me of a friend of mine, with only knowledge of a few years of high school Latin, who tried to pluralize the word and said *corpi*, after which he was immediately 'corrected' by another friend who very adamantly said "no, it's *corpūs*". That second friend had at that time just achieved his Bachelor's degree, majoring in Latin.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of material for you in the *Thesaurus Linguae Latinae*, VI, 3 ('habeo') col. 2454, 53 sqq., in col. 2455,65 sqq. also for the future (which might correspond more to the English 'I have to go' etc.). The secondary literature given in the TLL is probably outdated by now, but the examples are valid.

Comment: Can you give some of the examples here to make the answer more concrete? Also: Welcome to the site!